# Error: Compile Error: Invalid field IsPrimary for SObject Contact at line 21 column 13

Tags: apex

[image: code]

This is my code for the problem :
• Create a trigger on Contact to update the primary contacts phone number on parent Account
• Create a checkbox field on Contact “Is Primary” which will denote whether contact is primary or not.
• Insert/Update contact record with primary flag = true, to execute the trigger
• There cannot be more than one primary contacts associated with an Account.

```
trigger primaryContact on Contact (after insert, after update) {

      Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

      List<Account> updatedAccounts = new List<Account>();

      for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {

        accountIds.add(c.AccountId);

      }

      // Get accounts with their contacts.

      Map<Id,Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>([Select Id, Primary_Contact__c, (Select Id, Name from Contacts where IsPrimary__c = true) from Account where Id in :accountIds]);

      // Iterate over the new data from trigger

      for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {

        if (c.IsPrimary && accountMap.get(c.AccountId)) {

            Account updAccount = accountMap.get(c.AccountId);

            updAccount.Primary_Contact__c = c.Id;

            if (updAccount.Contacts != null && updAccount.Contacts.size()>0) { // This will identify if account already has primary contact set

              // Not sure what you want to do? Throw an error? or turn off the iS Primary on older contact?

            }



            updatedAccounts.add(updAccount);

        }

      }



      update updatedAccounts;

}
```

plz help me resolve ds

Answer (score 2):

At line 11 in image, you have `if (c.IsPrimary && accountMap.get(c.AccountId)) {`. I think it should be like `if (c.IsPrimary__c && accountMap.get(c.AccountId) != null) {`.

On the SOQL you used `c.IsPrimary__c` in where clause not the `IsPrimary`. There is no standard field with name `IsPrimary` on Contact object.

Comment: ya thanx for that but after correcting that I got this Error: Compile Error: AND operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions at line 11 column 31

Comment: @malvika change this if (c.IsPrimary__c && accountMap.get(c.AccountId)) { into `if (c.IsPrimary__c && accountMap.get(c.AccountId) != null) {`

Comment: woahoo thanx alot :)